# Best approach for name similarity

Tags: validation, comparison

As part of validation, we perform name similarity check and allow only if the threshold is reached. I got some help from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41053309/how-do-i-compare-the-similarity-of-person-names-using-a-metric) regarding the implementation and finally implemented [JaroWinkler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) algorithm. Recently we observed that it is not reliable for long names and some false names also cross the threshold.

I know that the algorithm is for measuring the edit distance between two sequences. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Just curious to know how financial institutions do this name validation.

[EDIT]:

I achieved better results with this approach.

1. split the name to get FN, MD, LN.
2. use the Levenshtein algorithm to calculate the match %. (Implemented the algorithm to match the requirements).
3. calculate the % of small name and return the average of the Percentage match.

This algorithm implementation has significantly removed the errors which I used to get with Jaro-Winkler.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot speak for all financial institutions, but when I was working in that arena, we maintained a list of names and surnames along with their origin. During a data factory run, names are compared against this file and any that are not recognised are sent to a drop file for further analysis.

Credit bureaus in particular maintain a list of person and household keys so if it is known that say, a John Doe lives at an address and a record comes in that says Jon Doe for the same address, this is deemed to be a match. N.B. there are of course edge cases where father and son have the same name which would require further data to separate.

This aside, there are (as you've already seen) various fuzzy matching algorithms like [Levenshtein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)'s that can assist further.

Comment: I work for a bank.  In a situation in which no identifier is given, the fiscal code is cross-referenced.  If that doesn't match, user is likely foreigner and so a secondary match using first name, last name, date of birth and some other fields are used.  Certainly it isn't fool-proof but errors are practically non-existent.